# using select query convert columns data as particular column

Tags: select

using select query convert columns data as particular column only using select query

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for

[pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

statement

> The PIVOT operator turns the values of
>   a specified column into column names,
>   effectively rotating a table.

Refer this post

[SQL SERVER – PIVOT and UNPIVOT Table Examples](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)

Comment: Wow, you actually understood that question/statement! I couldn't work out what 'rachit' was actually trying to say :P

Comment: ya it is possible but how to i use it plz instruct me